# layout with listview and text below

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a text below a listview and I need that if listview contains more items, to push the text down more. Because many items in my listview, causes the view to look bad. Look at the example to understand
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMPp7.png)

My code is

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <TextView

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Mañana"
        android:id="@+id/manianaTitle" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/listaManiana"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <TextView

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Tarde"
        android:id="@+id/tardeTitle" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/listaTarde"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <TextView

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Noche"
        android:id="@+id/nocheTitle" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/listaNoche"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to use a ListView with section. In that case you can categorize each section in your ListView instead of using many ListViews and TextViews.

I found this example from this [website](http://javatechig.com/android/listview-with-section-header-in-android) and I did some modification in the code

Create your List Item View

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/photo"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_margin="32dp"
    android:src="@drawable/female"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/photo_details"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/photo"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/photo"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Create a layout for the header section

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFF"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#FF000000" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Create an adapter for your List View

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.TreeSet;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 0;
private static final int TYPE_SEPARATOR = 1;

private ArrayList<EntityObject> mData = new ArrayList<String>();
private TreeSet<Integer> sectionHeader = new TreeSet<Integer>();

private LayoutInflater mInflater;

public CustomAdapter(Context context) {
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

public void addItem(final EntityObject item) {
    mData.add(item);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void addSectionHeaderItem(final String item) {
    mData.add(item);
    sectionHeader.add(mData.size() - 1);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return sectionHeader.contains(position) ? TYPE_SEPARATOR : TYPE_ITEM;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mData.size();
}

@Override
public String getItem(int position) {
    return mData.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    int rowType = getItemViewType(position);

    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        switch (rowType) {
        case TYPE_ITEM:
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.snippet_item1, null);
            holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.photo_details);
            holder.photo = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.photo)
            break;
        case TYPE_SEPARATOR:
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.snippet_item2, null);
            holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textSeparator);
            break;
        }
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.textView.setText(mData.get(position).getText());
    holder.setImageResource(mData.get(position).getImage());

    return convertView;
}

public static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView textView;
    public ImageView photo;
}
}
```